# How to initilize a dattimepicker plugin for a dynamicly created DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a page that will insert new html table rows dynamically.

Each row on the table, contains 2 inputs (left and right). Each two inputs need to be linked together to form a range selector using [Bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I created a function that should hook the datetimepicker plugin to each input, but for some reason that isn't working.

This function is triggered each time a new row is added to the DOM dynamicly.

```
function initilizeRangePicker(index) {

    var from = $('#NewMultipleEvent_' + index + '__StartsAt');
    var to = $('#NewMultipleEvent_' + index + '__EndsAt');

    from.datetimepicker({
        format: DateTimeFormat,
        useCurrent: false
    });

    to.datetimepicker({
        format: DateTimeFormat,
        useCurrent: false
    });

    from.on("dp.change", function (e) {
        to.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });

    to.on("dp.change", function (e) {
        from.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
}
```

I also tried changed that function to the following

```
function initilizeRangePicker(index) {

    var from = $('#NewMultipleEvent_' + index + '__StartsAt');
    var to = $('#NewMultipleEvent_' + index + '__EndsAt');

    $(document).on('datetimepicker', from, function (e) {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            format: DateTimeFormat,
            useCurrent: false
        });
    });

    $(document).on('datetimepicker', to, function (e) {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            format: DateTimeFormat,
            useCurrent: false
        });
    });


    from.on("dp.change", function (e) {
        to.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });

    to.on("dp.change", function (e) {
        from.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
}
```

but it is not working.

The `from` and `to` elements do exists and being added correctly.  I also validated that by logging the following `console.log(from.length, to.length);`

How can I correctly create the range selectors?

Comment: What's the value of **DateTimeFormat**?

Comment: The format is MM/DD/YYYY LT

Comment: Take a look to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v17y9vj1/) and let me know.

Comment: Define what you mean by 'linked' and 'not working'

Comment: @Hitham S. AlQadheeb what he measn by linked is that they must be related like this: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers, and shouldn't the tag of this be eonasdan-datetimepicker? as this is not the tarruda widget, even the tag has that clarification.

Comment: @William-H-M, thanks.  I added tag back as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It must be some mistake in your code because everything work as @gaetanoM already pointed out in comment

```js
function initilizeRangePicker(index) {

    var from = $('#NewMultipleEvent_' + index + '__StartsAt');
    var to = $('#NewMultipleEvent_' + index + '__EndsAt');

    from.datetimepicker();
    to.datetimepicker();

    from.on("dp.change", function (e) {
        to.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });

    to.on("dp.change", function (e) {
        from.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
}

function appendRow() {
  var index = $('.row').length;
 var idFrg = 'NewMultipleEvent_' + index;
  var row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
  ["__StartsAt", "__EndsAt"].forEach(function(side) {
   row.append('<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date" id="' + idFrg + side + '"><input type="text" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div></div></div>');
  });
  $("#wrapper").append(row);
  initilizeRangePicker(index)
  
}


$(document).ready(function() {
 initilizeRangePicker(0);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='NewMultipleEvent_0__StartsAt'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date dpck' id='NewMultipleEvent_0__EndsAt'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="appendRow()">Append Datepicker</button>
```

Comment: You should set on the option of the `to` picker `useCurrent: false` as per what the docs say https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1075